# Grep Apache version from shell

Tags: apache2, grep

with `apache2 -v` I get the following result:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.48 (Ubuntu) 
Server built:   2022-01-05T14:29:15
```

How can I get just "2.4.48" using grep?
Thanks

Comment: Your question can be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63526322/21222895)

Answer (score 1):

Probably everyone will have their own favorite way to do this, but *one* possible way would be to use grep's PCRE mode to match and discard the `/`, then match one or more non-whitespace characters:

```
apache2 -v | grep -Po '/\K\S+'
```